# How can I fix the PDF preflight error: "The 'Widths' array in a font has an invalid length"

Tags: pdf, fonts, truetype, opentype

I am trying to validate a PDF file as part of IngramSpark's pre-publishing workflow.
I upload the final PDF to be published, and their software (which I believe is pdfToolbox from Callas) runs a "preflight" check on the PDF.

I get this error message:
The 'Widths' array in a font has an invalid length

... but no advice on how to solve this.

Since I don't have access to pdfToolbox to run the preflight checks on my own, I have used VeraPDF (open source) to check the PDF. I am able the replicate the error in VeraPDF. When checking the PDF, VeraPDF provides a more detailed error message, as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AErgw.png)

And here is the text of the error message:

root/document[0]/pages[0](1 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](2 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[42]/font0

Widths array is missing or has invalid size 105 instead of 106

root/document[0]/pages[1](8 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](9 0 obj PDContentStream)/operators[10]/font0

Widths array is missing or has invalid size 80 instead of 81

root/document[0]/pages[11](38 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](39 0 obj
PDContentStream)/operators[66]/font0

Widths array is missing or has invalid size 51 instead of 52

=== end of VeraPDF error

So this error refers to a missing Widths array in two different fonts: EBGaramond-Regular (mentioned twice) and EBGaramond-Italic.

Here is what I have tried, without success:

- I have used the Google ttf (TrueType) version of these fonts: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/EB+Garamond
- I have embedded these fonts in the PDF.
- I have used the otf (OpenType) version of these fonts.
- I have Googled this error message and found a similar complaint, but without any solution:
  https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/acrobat-preflight-reports-the-quot-widths-quot-array-in-a-font-has-an-invalid-length/td-p/11580976

Any suggestions for a fix?

Just for reference, here are possible solutions that I have pondered:

Is the missing Widths array intrinsic to the EBGaramond-Regular and EBGaramond-Italic, and therefore unfixable, so I should try a different font?

Could the font files be edited to fix the missing Widths array?

Could the PDF file be edited to fix the missing Widths array?

Have I somehow embedded the fonts improperly in the PDF?

Comment: How do you create your pdfs? The error messages talk about missing arrays *or arrays of the wrong length*. As the lengths are given so explicitly, if assume it's the wrong lengths in your case. Thus, you have to fix the widths array in the font object in the pdf (not necessarily in the font program) .

Comment: I am using LibreOffice Writer to create the document and then export to PDF. So maybe LibreOffice PDF exporter is messing up the widths? I have tried exporting from LibreOffice using PDF/A-1b, PDF/A-2b, and PDF/A-3b... all without success. I have also tried the "Outlines ON" and "Outlines OFF" options in the LibreOffice export dialog box.

Comment: That sounds like a genuine LibreOffice error...

Comment: I have solved this problem, although I don't know exactly what caused the problem. Apparently some characters in the text (such emdashes and bullets) were not part of the main Garamond font that I was using, and were causing errors. These "bad characters" were discovered by selecting each section of text in LibreOffice, one at a time. Since selecting text that has two or more fonts results in LibreOffice not displaying the font name, we got an indication if the selected text had multiple (and unwanted) fonts in the text body. Then we could replace the bad chars with good ones.

Comment: It's great that you could solve the issue for yourself. Nonetheless there seems to be a LibreOffice bug, you only found and applied a work-around for your use case. So you still may open an issue at the LibreOffice site.

Answer (score 1):

This bug was introduced in LibreOffice 7.5 in https://gerrit.libreoffice.org/c/core/+/140125; and fixed in LibreOffice 7.6.2 in [tdf#157112](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=157112).